# Enviar Váriavel Ajax para PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Estou tendo dificuldades em enviar uma variável do Ajax para PHP, a situação é a seguinte:

Através de um `while`, são listado todos os álbuns disponíveis no banco de dados:

```
  include './bd/conecta.php';

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM album";
  $query = mysql_query($sql);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
      echo '<a href="">' . '<img  width="100px" heigth="100px" src="' . $row['capa_album'] . '"  onclick="alb(' . $row['id_album'] . ')" ></a>';
  }
```

Ai com o código Ajax eu consigo visualizar esse `id_album` através de um `alert`, porém não consigo enviar essa variável `id_album` para a página `fotos.php`.

```
function alb(codigo) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'fotos.php',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'id_album=' + codigo,
        success: function(data) {

            alert(codigo);
        }
    });
};
```

Na verdade nem redirecionando está para a página fotos.php, alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

A ideia do ajax é fazer requisições sem refresh, quando a resposta vier você usa o javascript pra fazer as alterações na página dando a impressão que tudo está ocorrendo em tempo real.

Assim, quando você clicar em um dos links montados o dado será enviado e processado para fotos.php, não haverá redirecionamento, será retornado para o ajax o que o fotos.php processar(escrever na tela para ser mais preciso).

tabela.php

```
 <table>
     <tr><td>CLIQUE EM MIM<td></tr>    
 </table>

 // bloco ajax
 $('tr').click(function(){
     $.ajax({type:'get';
         url:'numero.php',
         success: function(i){$('table tr').html('<td>'+i+'</td>')}
     })
 });
```

numero.php

```
echo 1
```

vai produzir:

```
 <table>
     <tr><td>1<td></tr>    
 </table>
```